# npm package is causing a SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' error in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, cookies, next.js

I am building a Next.js React site and have run into a problem I can't seem to fix. The issue is I am using a npm package called nookie which is causing an error in IE11 and resulting in issue on my site. The error IE is returning is a `SCRIPT1006: Expected')'`

This is where the error is happening in the code of the package:

[image]

So when I did some research on what is happening I learned that Internet Explorer does not understand default values for arguments.

I have been trying to find a polyfill or babel solution for this but have yet to find one.

Has anyone dealt with a "default values for arguments" issue in IE11 before and found a solution that would work for me.

Some other notes are:

I do have these polyfills already which has fixed es issues for me before but they don't seem to be making a difference:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.3/es6-sham.min.js" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js" />`

One other note is that I may just end up having to use a different package but I am gaining a lot of other benefits from this particular package since I am using Next.js and it is meant for Next so I am trying my best to keep this package alive for me.

Thanks

Comment: So you need to use babel to transpile the code or find a library that will work with IE11

Comment: @epascarello I have been looking at a babel transpile solution but unfortunately, my babel knowledge isn't the best so I am having difficulties figuring out how to go about transpiling solution. Would you have any good references to go off of? I currently have been reading the docs but it is a bit confusing since I am using the next.js way of doing it as well.

Comment: this might help you https://github.com/maticzav/nookies/issues/8#issuecomment-434203318